# How do you interpret "barred face identity mask"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I don't quite understand these(below) lines of a poem named "The Laburnum top":

She stokes it full, then flirts out to a branch-end showing her "barred face identity mask"

Would the correct parse be (barred) (face identity mask)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this reference http://www.english-for-students.com/The-Laburnum-Top.html it is indeed "barred", and see several commentaries that also refer to "barred".

```
 barred face
```

is the bird's face, striped with shadows, which is as though she is wearing a mask. An

```
identity mask
```

is an artistic mask, designed and made (or chosen) by the wearer to express their character or identity.

Answer (score 1):

I would say "a barred identity mask" leaving out "face" because "mask" as "a covering for a face" will explain it. It might be inaccurate, though.

An identity mask is a mask for people who want to hide/change their true appearance. A bank robber may use it to hide their face behind it. A theatre performer may wear it to entertain the spectators.

[image]

"Barred" as an adjective means either "having bars or stripes" or "marked with bands of light or colour".

[image]